# apt-cache/apt search packages that are not installed

Tags: apt, search, apt-cache

I can search packages with `apt-cache search <package_name>`, or search installed packages with `apt list --installed | grep <package_name>`.

How about packages that are not installed? How do I search the list of non-installed package with `apt-cache` or `apt`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see them like this... but not in nice colours

```
apt list --installed=false | grep -v '\[installed'
```

Comment: Are you sure nothing will come before `installed`, or the order of `installed`, `automatic` get reversed?

Comment: my results are, `installed` always comes first and before `automatic`. I didn't find `installed` anywhere in the package list other than at the end of the lines @KongChunHo

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this does not use `apt-cache` or `apt`, but `aptitude` provides some powerful ways of searching:

```
aptitude search '!~i ^apt*'
```

or equivalently,

```
aptitude search '?not(?installed) ^apt*'
```

produces an output like:

```
p   apt-forktracer                                                                         - utility for tracking non-official package versions
p   apt-listbugs                                                                           - tool which lists critical bugs before each APT installation
p   apt-listdifferences                                                                    - source differences notification tool
p   apt-mirror                                                                             - APT sources mirroring tool
p   apt-move                                                                               - maintain Debian packages in a package pool
p   apt-offline                                                                            - offline APT package manager
p   apt-offline-gui                                                                        - offline APT package manager - GUI
p   apt-rdepends                                                                           - recursively lists package dependencies
p   apt-show-source                                                                        - Shows source-package information
p   apt-show-versions                                                                      - lists available package versions with distribution
p   apt-src                                                                                - manage Debian source packages
p   apt-transport-https                                                                    - https download transport for APT
...
```

Note that the first letter of each line gives the state of the package; here are some common ones:

```
p     no trace of the package exists on system
c     package has configuration files remaining on system
v     virtual package
```